# How to add and multiply text boxes together in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How do I add the following text boxes together with the logic below?

```
oneTextBox = $120.00,
twoTextBox = .03*oneTextBox,
threeTextBox = oneTextBox + twoTextBox
```

I would also like the units of each text box to be in dollars ($).

---

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var VertPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('VertPanel');

  var oneTextBox = app.createTextBox().setText("$120.00").setId("oneTextBox").setName("oneTextBox");
  var twoTextBox = app.createTextBox().setId("twoTextBox").setName("twoTextBox");
  var threeTextBox = app.createTextBox().setId("threeTextBox").setName("threeTextBox");

  app.add(VertPanel);
  VertPanel.add(oneTextBox).add(twoTextBox).add(threeTextBox);

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by e.parameter.oneTextBox in the handler function is a string, in your example it should be "$120.00," and what you want is a numeric value... what I'd suggest is to use a `replace()` to remove all non numeric characters and convert that to a number like this :

```
var oneTextBoxNumValue = Number(e.parameter.oneTextBox.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));// the regex ^0-9 takes everything not between 0 and 9 (and replace by '')
```

Using the same process on other textBoxes you can do everything you want with math operations after this conversion.

To get the results in $, simply add a '$' to your result

```
getElementById('oneTextBox').setText(resultNumeric+"$")
```

the only tricky thing is the decimal point, you'll need to take this into account in your conversion : `$120.00,` will become 12000 in numeric value so don't forget to divide the result somewhere or your stuff will become very expensive  ! ;-)
Also I've had some rounding errors sometimes but it's always possible to handle quite easily, for example in a similar case I had to use something like this to get the correct result : *(2.00 instead of 1.99 if quant = 2 in the example below, note that I divide the integer by 100 to get value with 2 decimals)*

```
 var total = parseInt(Number(quant)*valtotal*100+0.01)/100;
```

Hoping it will give some ideas to start with.

**EDIT :** here is a small code to illustrate :

```
function calcTest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('TextField Calculator');
  var button = app.createButton('Calculate');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('calc');
  button.addClickHandler(handler); 
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
  grid.setText(0, 0, 'value1 ');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('value1').setText('$ 45.00/unit'));
  grid.setText(1, 0, 'value2');
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('value2').setText('3 units'));
  grid.setText(2, 0, 'press button to calculate');
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, button);
  grid.setText(3, 0, 'value3 = value1*1.35');
  grid.setWidget(3, 1, app.createTextBox().setId('value3').setEnabled(false));
  grid.setText(4, 0,'sum value1 + value2 + value3');
  grid.setWidget(4, 1, app.createTextBox().setId('sum').setEnabled(false));
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  app.add(grid);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(app);
  }

function calc(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var value1 = Number(e.parameter.value1.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))/100;
   var value2 = Number(e.parameter.value2.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
   var calcvalue = parseInt(value1*1.35*100)/100
   var sumcalc = calcvalue+value1+value2
   app.getElementById('value3').setText('$ '+calcvalue)
   app.getElementById('sum').setText(sumcalc+' without unit;)')
   return app
  }
```

[image]

**EDIT 2 :** here is another code, a function that I use in an application to convert string values to Euros, it is slightly different in its approach but works pretty well.

```
  function toEuro(val){
  if(val==''){temp='';return temp}
  var temp = val.toString().replace(/[^\d\.-]/g,'').split('.');
  if(temp[0]==''){temp[0]='0'}
  if(temp.length==1){var result = temp[0]+',00 €'}
  else{
  var int = temp[0]
  var dec = temp[1]
      if(dec.length==1){var result=int+','+dec+'0 €'}else{var result=int+','+dec+' €'}
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: Hey Serge. You going to write a book? You have come a long way!

Comment: Ha ha... thanks Michael, It's true that I'm too enthousiast sometimes ! but, to be honest I take as much as I give, answering is a very efficient learning method ;)

Comment: This is perfect... yet again... thx again Serge.  You have seriously taught me so much since I have started my programming journey.  I can't thank you enough.  One additional question. How do I make the decimal place only two decimals in the text boxes if I were to get a number such as 2000.1251231? oh... and I would like it to round up if the 3rd decimal place is 5 or greater and not round at all if the  3rd decimal place is 4 or less.

Comment: Javascript has build-in method to handle that, in the example code above you could use this line of code to get 2 decimal places with rounding : `var sumcalc = Math.round(100*(calcvalue+value1+value2))/100`